# Android - The following classes could not be instantiated

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm a total beginner I just started learning android development and i'm trying to print  "Hello World" with the "material light theme" but I have this problem

```
the following classes could not be instantiated 
 - android.support.design.widget.coordinatorLayout
 - android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
 - android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
```

Comment: Change material light theme into NoActionBar Theme

Answer (score 4):

Did you add theese lines in your `build.gradle` :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

And then sync , rebuild your project. Also update `Android Sdk Tools` in `Sdk Manager` to latest version.

@Edit , for @Maza :

First of all open `build.gradle` like, If you can't see this page in left side of `Android Studio` try to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> keys:

[image]

Then you should see a window like that :

[image]

Thats it. Now you can add any dependencies in your `build.gradle` !

Comment: You can also add these dependencies through the File > Project Structure dialog rather than adding the lines by hand to the `build.gradle` file. Select the module, then the dependencies tab. Then click on the "+" icon on the right margin, and select the dependencies you need.

Comment: @TedHopp thats the another amazing way too . Thanks , i will edit my answer include your way with your permission ?

Comment: No need to ask for permission. Everything on SO is for everyone to use as they see fit. Comments are a great source of material for improving one's answers; I've done it many times.

Comment: @TedHopp thanks, this comment way constructive too. I think structure of SO is so good. There is an answer here and you can support it by editing and comments .

Comment: can you provide screenshots of how to do it  cuz i can't use android studio properly :/

Comment: i did exactly what you told me to do but it didn't work

Comment: @Can you come with screenshot , which activity using that appbarlayout and floating actionbutton ? Just need screenshot of Android Studio